# local.xml is not loading in magento

Tags: magento

I want to delete the recently viewed products at the category view page. I have created my local.xml in public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout

I have looked at several potential solutions on the internet but nothing seems to work. I use the following code at the moment:

```
<default><reference<reference name="right">  
<remove name="right.reports.product.viewed"/> </reference> </default>
```

I also have tried left, but not seems to work. Could someone help me how to succeed loading local.xml? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The above solution even if written correctly, will remove the right side reports view from all the pages (I am hoping that this needs to be removed only from CATEGORY VIEW page).

Firstly, create local.xml file in custom theme folder. I would suggest creating custom package too like below:

/app/design/frontend/customPackage/customTheme/layout/

However, since you are using BASE

/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml

The code must be as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>       
    <layout version="0.1.0">
        <default>
            <catalog_category_default>
                <reference name="right">
                    <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed"/>
                </reference>
            </catalog_category_default>
        </default>
    </layout>
```

This will work only if the template for  is set to 2columns-right.phtml

Hope this helps.

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 0):

If you installed a theme try to copy local.xml file to theme's layout directory
like this "\app\design\frontend\THEME_DIR\layout\local.xml"

also you have a syntax error in your xml
it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
<reference name="right">  
<remove name="right.reports.product.viewed"/>
</reference>
</default>
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the fast response, however it still doesnt work.

Comment: did you reset cache after change?